# HTML Code execution from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I obtain the following string during runtime:

```
<path id= "3" d=" M 70.7107 40.8248 L -1.42109e-014 -7.10543e-015 " />
<path id= "4" d=" M 70.7107 -40.8248 L 70.7107 40.8248 " />
```

and generate an SVG Element as follows

```
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
```

Now I would like to generate the two path elements as children of the dynamically created SVG Element. Do you have some hints for me? Thanks a lot in advance,

BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
svg.innerHTML = '<path id= "3" d=" M 70.7107 40.8248 L -1.42109e-014 -7.10543e-015 " /> <path id= "4" d=" M 70.7107 -40.8248 L 70.7107 40.8248 " />';
document.body.appendChild(svg); //replace document.body with wherever you want to put your svg
```

via https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild

Or maybe easier:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="svgDiv"></div>
    <script>
    var div = document.getElementById("svgDiv");
    var paths = '<path id= "3" d=" M 70.7107 40.8248 L -1.42109e-014 -7.10543e-015 " /> <path id= "4" d=" M 70.7107 -40.8248 L 70.7107 40.8248 " />';
    div.innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">' + paths + '</svg>';
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, you might also want to consider using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to make DOM manipulation easier.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Maybe I was not clear. I only have ONE String with multiple path elements. To avoid seperating the string in multiple substrings I search for some command like: svg.addMultipleChildrenByHTMLString(...)  :-)

Comment: I see, then use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML

Comment: Also appendChild() seems to expect an Object and does not work with a string in my case.

Comment: innerHTML is quite close to what I want to do. Thanks for that. Unfortunately this routine automatically attaches an </path> tag at the end of my string for each path element in the string (prior to the closing </svg> tag). This seems to screw up everything if I have more than one path in the string. Also I cannot access the path elements as children of my div element. Any idea?

Comment: `<path></path>` is equivalent to `<path />` since it's XML